# How can I query an exact value (with space) in elasticsearch array list

Tags: arrays, elasticsearch

I trying to use term filter to find exact tag-names in array list eg.

```
   tag_names: ["tea", "green tea"]
```

I use

```
{"filter": {"term": {"tag_names": "green tea"}}}
```

It give me a wrong result. I googled many links, just found solution to do exact match with array list (but without space).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to search for exact term , make sure that the field you are searching in is `not_analyzed`. `Term Query` works for `not_analyzed` field.

If your field is `analyzed`, then the term `green tea` will be tokenized into two terms, `green` and `tea`. In that case you might need to use `match query` or `query_string` query.Use it like

```
{
"query": {
   "query_string": {
      "default_field": "tag_names",
      "query": "green tea"
    }
  }
}
```

Study about `analyzed` and `non anlyzed` [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping-intro.html#_index_2)

You can see whether `tag_names` field is `analyzed` or `not_analyzed` using

```
GET /index/type/_mapping
```

Comment: can you please check it once? I have tried the above answer you gave. But still its tokenizing the fields. I am a regular user not an expert but still i just want you to cross check. My field mapping is analyzed and still its tokenizing when using query_string. Thanks your help will be apreciated..

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
{  
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": 
            {
                "match" : {
                    "tag_names" : {
                        "query":"green tea",
                        "operator":"and"
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
GET index/type/_search
{
 "query":{
    "term": {
       "tag_names": {
          "value": "green"
         }
      }
   }  
}
```

**Note:** Make sure **term** filter work for one term if you have more than one word to search for you can use **query_string** filter.
if you want exact search so in your mapping of that index , that particular field must be set to not_analysed.

If you have multiple terms to search individually in each document try this one..

```
 GET index/type/_search
 {
      "query":{
          "terms": {
             "tag_names": ["green","tea"]
          }
      }
  }
```

Comment: It's not that `term filter` works only for one term. Please  look at my answer to know more.

Comment: @Richa can you please check it once? I have tried the above answer you gave. But still its tokenizing the fields. I am a regular user not an expert but still i just want you to cross check. My field mapping is set to analyzed and still its tokenizing when i am using query_string. Thanks your help will be apreciated..